# Pandas: Get last, penultimate, antepenultimate month values

Tags: python, pandas, date

I am stuck at getting the last, penultimate and antepenultimate monthly values of a variable in python GIVEN a reference date. I
I have two dataframes:

| reference_date | id_cliente |
| --- | --- |
| 201504 | A8781 |
| 201706 | B7638 |
| 201401 | A8781 |

In this dataframe, the clients can appear more than once ( so there are some clients that have more than one reference date).

And the other:

| date | id_client | sales |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 201310 | A8781 | 1 |
| 201311 | A8781 | 2 |
| 201312 | A8781 | 3 |
| 201503 | A8781 | 3200 |
| 201502 | A8781 | 6500 |
| 201501 | A8781 | 3400 |
| 201504 | A8781 | 3400 |
| 201703 | B7638 | 300 |
| 201704 | B7638 | 200 |
| 201705 | B7638 | 100 |
| 201706 | B7638 | 3500 |

So my desired output is:

| reference_date | id_client | last_date | penultimate_date | antepenultimate_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 201504 | A8781 | 3200 | 6500 | 3400 |
| 201706 | B7638 | 100 | 200 | 300 |
| 201401 | A8781 | 1 | 2 | 3 |

I know that it's possible to get that with numpy and pandas functions but I am not able to find the solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First filter rows after `df2['date']` by `df1['reference_date']` per `id_cliente` by [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) compared for greater by [`Series.gt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.gt.html) and filtered in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing), then sorting by [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) for correct order:

```
s = df1.set_index('id_cliente')['reference_date']
df = (df2[df2['id_client'].map(s).gt(df2['date'])]
          .sort_values(['id_client','date'], ascending=[True, False]))
```

Then create helper column by counter by [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) for filter 3 rows and also is used for pivoting by [`DataFrame.pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html):

```
df['g'] = df.groupby('id_client').cumcount()

df = df[df['g'].lt(3)].copy()

df = df.pivot('id_client','g','sales')
```

Last set new columns names, add `reference_date` by mapping and convert index to column:

```
df.columns = ['last_date','penultimate_date','antepenultimate_date']
df = df.reset_index()
df.insert(0,'reference_date', df['id_client'].map(s))
print (df)
   reference_date id_client  last_date  penultimate_date  antepenultimate_date
0          201504     A8781       3200              6500                  3400
1          201706     B7638        100               200                   300
```

EDIT: Similar answer for multiple `id_cliente` - instead `map` is used [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) and for distinguish duplicated `id_cliente` is used [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html):

```
df1['groups'] = df1.groupby('id_cliente').cumcount()

df = df2.merge(df1, left_on='id_client', right_on='id_cliente')

df = (df[df['reference_date'].gt(df['date'])]
           .sort_values(['groups','id_client','date'], ascending=[True, True, False])
          )

df['g'] = df.groupby(['id_client','groups']).cumcount()

df = df[df['g'].lt(3)].copy()

df = df.pivot(['groups','id_client'],'g','sales')
print (df)

df.columns = ['last_date','penultimate_date','antepenultimate_date']

df = df1.join(df, on=['groups','id_cliente']).drop('groups', axis=1)

print (df)
   reference_date id_cliente  last_date  penultimate_date  \
0          201504      A8781       3200              6500   
1          201706      B7638        100               200   
2          201401      A8781          3                 2   

   antepenultimate_date  
0                  3400  
1                   300  
2                     1
```

Comment: thanks for your answer! It gives me the following error after executing first two lines: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued index objects

Comment: @GusCR - It means `id_cliente` are duplicated, if need maximal `date` per `id_cliente` change `s = df1.set_index('id_cliente')['reference_date']` to `s = df1.groupby('id_cliente')['reference_date'].max()`

Comment: @jezreael I actually need it for all clients despite it is duplicated or not ...(the client can be duplicated but not the combination id_client and reference _date)

Comment: @GusCR - I think change sample data for see how change my solution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226045/discussion-between-gus-cr-and-jezrael).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the structure of the dataframes in your examples -
Aggregate the second dataframe on `date` column and pick the nth entries. You can use the `.groupby.nth()` with a `.pivot()` for this task .

```
n_obs = 3 # number of observations per item
grouped = df2[['id_client', 'sales']].groupby('id_client').nth(list(range(n_obs))

# Reformat the table to desired shape for last 3 values, change 
grouped.assign(row_num=grouped.index%n_obs).pivot(
    index='id_client', columns='row_num', values='sales').rename_axis(
        '', axis=1).reset_index().rename(
            columns={0:'last', 1:'penulltimate', 2:'antepenultimate'})
```

**Output:**

```
    id_client   last    penulltimate    antepenultimate
0   A8781       3200    6500            3400
1   B7638       300     200             100
```

You can now merge this into your original dataframe on the id_client field.

Refer to: [GroupBy nth](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.nth.html)

Comment: thanks for your time. This is not the solution. I have to find the last 3 values given the reference date of each client...